# Joining and comparing a large number of input files from bash

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, while-loop

I want to read lines from 29 files and processing these lines and putting them in if statement.

In this example i created 3 sample files and one shell script file which basically reading files using while loop and read these lines from each files and process using sed with an if statement, this if statement is used to check to see the first variables(example abc.def) in all files and copy their values to a file.

Example:

```
a.txt
    abc.def=123
    efg.hij=45666
    kml.nop=789
    qrs.tuv=901
    wxy.zabc=234
b.txt
    abc.def=123
    efg.hij=45666
    kml.nop=897
    klm.nop=123
    qrs.tuv=901
    wxy.zabc=234
c.txt
    abc.def=12344
    efg.hij=456
    kml.nop=123
    klm.nop=789
    wxy.zabc=234

sprict.sh

    #!/bash/bin

    count=1
    while IFS= read -r lineA && IFS= read -r lineB <&3 && IFS= read -r lineC <&4; do
    #splitting the line into two,example from line abc.def=123 slit varaibles as "abc.def" and "123"
    A1=`echo "$lineA" | sed -e 's/\=\(.*\)//' `
    A2=`echo "$lineA" | sed -e 's/^[^=]*=//' `
    B1=`echo "$lineB" | sed -e 's/\=\(.*\)//' `
    B2=`echo "$lineB" | sed -e 's/^[^=]*=//' `      
    C1=`echo "$lineC" | sed -e 's/\=\(.*\)//' `
    C2=`echo "$lineC" | sed -e 's/^[^=]*=//' `
    if [ [ "$A1" = "$B1" && "$A1" = "$C1"]];then
    echo -e "<variable id=\"$A1\">\t
    <a2>"$A2"</a2>\t
    <b2>"$B2"</b2>\t
    <c2>"$C2"</c2>\t
    </variable>\n" >> common.txt                    
    fi
    done <a.txt 3<b.txt 4<c.txt
```

Expected output is:

```
<variable id="abc.def">
   <a2>123</a2>
   <b2>123</b2>
   <c2>12344</c2>
</variable>
<variable id="efg.hij">
   <a2>456</a2>
   <b2>45666</b2>
   <c2>45666</c2>
</variable>
<variable id="kml.nop">
   <a2>789</a2>
   <b2>897</b2>
   <c2>123</c2>
</variable>
```

Comment: This is really horrible code. Consider using `xmlstarlet ed` to build your XML documents; using an array to store the list of files you want to read from and iterating over it, and another array to store content which has been read; and otherwise trying to follow the "one/two/many" rule.

Comment: Hi Charles, thanks for your honest feedback, since i am not good with xml file processing, can you give a sample code that makes me to start with.

Comment: What happened to `wxy.zabc` and `klm.nopp` and `abca.def` in the sample output and why?  Is it only keys that appear in all three files that are processed?  (It can't be that; `wxy.zabc` appears in all three.)  And in the more general 29 file case, only keys that appear in all 29 files that are listed? With 29 files, what coding is used in the tags (`<a2>`, `<b2>`, ...) for letters after `z` (files 27, 28, 29)?

Comment: expected output will be always having all common matching varaibles with multiple values.

Comment: Thanks to every one how helped in solving this issue, i tried all solutions with my 29 files inputing to a script, however the solution that @Hai has provided was very good and it worked without any issues even with the files that are not in proper order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind a different language other than *bash*, may I suggest *awk* (just because I am familiar with it, also because it is good a text processing). Here is my *awk* solution, which I call *text2xml.awk*:

```
BEGIN {
    FS="=" # Use the equal sign as field separator
}

# When we encounter a new file, establish a new tag based on the file
# name
#   tag:      tag names,  (a2, b2, c2, ...)
#   tagfound: keep track of which tag has been found
#   tags:     array of tag names, where tags[0] = "a2", ...
#   tagcount: number of tags
FNR == 1 {
    tag = FILENAME
    sub(/\..*$/, "2", tag) # Replace extension with number 2, a.txt ==> a2
    if (!(tag in tagfound)) {
        tags[tagcount++] = tag
    }
    tagfound[tag] = 1
}

# For each line in each file, we parse the id, add that id to a list
# then store the value for later display.
#   id:      abc.def, efg.hij, ...
#   idfound: keep track of which id has been found
#   ids:     List of id, ids[0] = "abc.def", ...
#   values:  two-dimensional array, values[id,tag] stores the right-
#            hand-side of the equal sign
{
    sub(/^ */, "") # Remove leading spaces
    if (!($1 in idfound)) { ids[idcount++] = $1 }
    idfound[$1] = 1
    values[$1,tag] = $2
}

# Loop through the ids and tags, display the XML
END {
    for (i=0; i<idcount; i++) {
        id = ids[i]
        printf "<variable id=\"%s\">\n", id
        for (j=0; j<tagcount; j++) {
            tag = tags[j]
            printf "  <%s>%s</%s>\n", tag, values[id,tag], tag
        }
        printf "</variable>\n"
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
awk -f text2xml.awk a.txt b.txt c.txt  # Try out with 3 files
awk -f text2xml.awk *.txt              # For all .txt files
```

## Discussion

I hope I put enough comments in the code to make sense to you. Please feel free to ask more questions if needed.

- The order of the IDs depend on how they appear within the text files
- The order of the tags (a2, b2, c2, ...) depends on the order of the files from the command line
- For those who know *awk*, we could just iterate through the `idfound` array and forget about `ids` and `idcount`. However, that approach does not guarantee the order of the IDs; and I have a feeling that order matters. The same is true for `tagfound`, `tagcount`, and `tags`.
- This solution works for 3 files, it should work for 29 files and beyond.
- I am testing this solution on Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion, but it should work with other platforms.

## Update

Per phani's request, I fix the code to strip *.txt* off the tag. Replace the following line:

```
    sub(/\..*$/, "2", tag) # Replace extension with number 2, a.txt ==> a2
```

with:

```
    sub(/\.txt$/, "", tag) # Remove the .txt extension
```

Comment: Thanks for the code @Hai, I like your logic and coding style. if my file name is abc.01.txt, can i pass abc.01 as tag and remove .txt extension?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `read` to simplify splitting each line into a name and value, and use a pre-built template with `printf` to simplify the output. Also, you had a few syntax errors in your `if` statement: whitespace matters.

The shell reserves file descriptors greater than 10 for its own use, so your approach won't scale well for 29 input files. In `bash` 4.1 and later, you can let `bash` allocate the file descriptors.

```
#!/bash/bin

# Redirect from each input file, using bash-assigned file descriptors
exec {afile}<a.txt
exec {bfile}<b.txt
exec {cfile}<c.txt

template='<variable="%s">\n\t<a2>%s</a2>\n\t<b2>%s</b2>\n\t<c2>%s</c2>\n</variable>\n'
while IFS="=" read -r -u "$afile" A1 A2 &&
      IFS="=" read -r -u "$bfile" B1 B2 &&
      IFS="=" read -r -u "$cfile" C1 C2; do

  if [[ "$A1" = "$B1" && "$A1" = "$C1" ]]; then
    printf "$template" "$A1" "$A2" "$B2" "$C2"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Much, _much_ better than the original code. Would still want to use real XML generation tools to build well-formed output when the inputs don't behave, but that's a last-stretch item. Was `{afile}<a.txt` introduced in 4.0? I thought it was somewhat later than that, 4.1 or 4.2, but could be wrong.

Comment: Question about correctness -- do we have an ordering guarantee that the variable names will be at the same positions?

Comment: good question and forgot to mention, I just realized that ordering is not guaranteed.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It appears to be a 4.1 addition; I'll note that in the answer.

Comment: @phani - As long as only the order differs, you can sort them first. If there could be missing variables in one file or another, you're probably better off writing the program in a language more suited to general data processing.

Comment: @chepner Eh -- it's possible to deal with missing variables; note the use of join in my answer (recursively, to deal with arbitrary numbers of inputs).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I had thought of `join`, but wasn't up to figuring out how to use it with a large set of files. Very nice.

Answer (score 3):

The below compares any arbitrary number of files, and does not require their contents to be in order (as the solution given by chepner does). It also uses XMLStarlet to generate XML-formatted output, guaranteeing well-formedness.

This does mean that XMLStarlet needs to be installed on your system; it's generally available packaged for modern releases of major operating systems.

```
#!/bin/bash

join_files() {
  local first
  if (( $# == 1 )); then
    sort <"$1"
  elif (( $# == 2 )); then
    join -t= <(sort <"$1") <(sort <"$2")
  elif (( $# > 2 )); then
    first=$1; shift
    join -t= <(sort <"$first") <(join_files "$@")
  fi
}

main() {
  declare -a items
  {
  printf '%s\n' '(root'
  while IFS='=' read -r -a items; do
    set -- "${items[@]}"
    name=$1; shift
    printf '%s\n' '(variable' "Aid $name"
    item_num=1
    for item; do
      printf '%s\n' "(a$item_num" "-$item" ")a$item_num"
      (( item_num++ ))
    done
    printf '%s\n' ')variable'
  done < <(join_files "$@")
  printf '%s\n' ')root'
  } | xmlstarlet depyx | xmlstarlet fo
}

main a.txt b.txt c.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, i will try this and update you with results.

Comment: when i tried this code, i got the following error `/cygdrive/c/files.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
/cygdrive/c/files.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `$'{\r''
'cygdrive/c/files.sh: line 3: `join_files() {
` . I tried dos2unix command and still i am seeing this error.

Comment: @phani That error definitely is an encoding problem (the kind of thing dos2unix fixes), not a problem with the script. If dos2unix doesn't fix it, that's a cygwin problem, and needs a separate question. And yes, this supports unordered variables.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. You have misplaced the spaces in the if block. It should be like this:

```
if [[ "$A1" = "$B1" && "$A1" = "$C1" ]];then
```

Note that there is no space between the opening brackets, and there is a space before the closing ones.

Also you have some typos in your test files. In `a.txt` you should change

```
klm.nop=789
```

to

```
kml.nop=789
```

And in `c.txt` you should change

```
abca.def=12344
```

to

```
abc.def=12344
```

Comment: I edited the files and still it didnt worked, but thanks for taking time and adding your views.